# Duda con el paso por referencia y módulos en C

Tags: c, array, matrices, punteros

En mi programa estoy usando módulos .h y sus correspondientes .c para estructurar mejor el código. El problema es que debo pasar por referencia una matriz dinámica a una de estas funciones del .h (y trabajarla en su .c), pero al hacer comprobaciones antes de entrar en la función y después de entrar en la función, el valor por ejemplo de la posición [0][0] no ha cambiado. En cambio, cuando modifico el valor de esa misma casilla en una función en el propio main.c, al hacer una comprobación después de esta función, SÍ que el valor es el que yo he querido. Tengo algún error de sintaxis?
Gracias.

El main.c es el siguiente

```
#include "logica.h"
#include "comandes.h"
#include "grafica.h"

void modificaPuntero (char **posicio_taulell) {
    posicio_taulell[0][0] = 'z';

}

int main(void){
int opcio, sortir = FALSE, allegro_run = FALSE;
Jugador jugador;
int i, j;
char **posicio_taulell;

while (!sortir) {
    opcio = mostraMenu();
    switch (opcio) {
        case 1:
            printf("\nAntes de comenzar es %c", posicio_taulell[0][0]);
            funcionModulo(posicio_taulell);
            printf("\nDespues de la funcion del modulo la primera casilla es: %c. ", posicio_taulell[0][0]);
            modificaPuntero(posicio_taulell);
            printf("\nPrimera casilla despues de la funcion en el main.c: %c.", posicio_taulell[0][0]);
            obreFinestraGrafica (jugador, posicio_taulell);
```

Esta es la función correspondiente a logica.c del modulo logica.h

```
void funcionModulo(char **posicio_taulell) {
    int filas = 9, columnas = 9;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char aux;
    posicio_taulell = (char **)malloc (filas * sizeof(char*));
    if (posicio_taulell == NULL) {
        printf("\nError al reservar memoria.\n");
    }
    else {
     for (i = 0;  i < filas;  i++) {
        posicio_taulell[i] = (char *)malloc (columnas * sizeof(char));
        if (posicio_taulell[i] == NULL) {
            printf("\nError al reservar memoria.\n");
        }
    }
    i = 0;
}
posicio_taulell[0][0] = 'b'; //Asigno un valor arbitrario para comprobar si se modifica en el main.c
printf("\nPrimera posicion dentro la funcion del modulo es %c.",posicio_taulell[0][0]);
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se puede observar como parece que el valor de la matriz al volver al main.c no se conserva, pero cuando hago una función en el propio main.c el valor si que se conserva

Comment: Los `.h` no tienen ningún efecto en lo que describes; se usan solo para separar la cabecera de las funciones de su implementación. Dicho esto, ¿estás seguro de que al enlazar/linkar estás recompilando la librería?

Comment: Gracias, ya está modificada la pregunta

Comment: Este problema no se puede reporducir sin un [mcve]... ¿Cómo esperas que podamos probar tu programa y ver si tenemos el mismo resultado que tú?

Comment: He añadido un ejemplo completo, espero que les sirva

Answer (score 1):

Parece que `funcionModulo` pretende crear un puntero `**` y "retornar" su valor, pero no a través de return, sino a través de un paso por referencia. Para poder modificar una variable por referencia, tendrías que pasarle su dirección, es decir, desde `main()` llamarlo así:

```
 funcionModulo(&posicio_taulell);
```

Pero naturalmente eso implica que esa función debe recibir un puntero a un puntero `**`, es decir, debería ser:

```
void funcionModulo(char ***posicio_taulell) {
 // ...
}
```

y, francamente, tres `***` ya me parece muy difícil de seguir (el código de la función cambiaría, y deberías poner `*posicio_taulell` en donde antes ponías `posicio_taulell`).

¿Por qué no hacer que esa función retorne el puntero que ha creado? Es decir, algo así:

```
char **funcionModulo(void) {
    // ...
    posicio_taulell = (char **)malloc (filas * sizeof(char*));
    // ... resto de la inicialización
    return posicio_taulell;
}
```

Desde el programa principal se llamaría así:

```
 posicio_taulell = funcionModulo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Centrémonos en estas primeras líneas ya que el resto son irrelevantes:

```
printf("\nAntes de comenzar es %c", posicio_taulell[0][0]);
funcionModulo(posicio_taulell);
printf("\nDespues de la funcion del modulo la primera casilla es: %c. ", posicio_taulell[0][0]);
modificaPuntero(posicio_taulell);
```

En la primera línea, accedes a `posicio_taulell[0][0]`, pero ... ¿Dónde se inicializa exactamente `posicio_taulell`?

La respuesta la encontramos en `funcionModulo`:

```
void funcionModulo(char **posicio_taulell) {
    int filas = 9, columnas = 9;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char aux;
    posicio_taulell = (char **)malloc (filas * sizeof(char*)); // <<--- AQUI!!!
```

Es decir, se inicializa **después del primer uso**. Tienes suerte de que el sistema operativo no haya matado tu programa. Ahí ya tienes el primer error de tu código.

El segundo puede no ser muy obvio pero ahí está y para verlo mejor vamos a eliminar punteros. ¿Qué salida crees que arrojará el siguiente código?:

```
void func(int var)
{ var = 1; }

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  func(a);
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

A ti te está pasando eso mismo:

```
void funcionModulo(char **posicio_taulell);
```

En esta función, `posicio_taulell` es una variable **local** de la función, luego cualquier instrucción del tipo `posicio_taulell = /* ... */` será un cambio local. Los cambios que se verán reflejados fuera de la función serán aquellos del tipo `posicio_taulell[i] = /* ... */`.

Y tu podrás pensar... vale, la primera asignación es un cambio local... pero el resto son cambios persistentes:

```
void funcionModulo(char **posicio_taulell) {
    int filas = 9, columnas = 9;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char aux;
    posicio_taulell = (char **)malloc (filas * sizeof(char*)); // LOCAL
    if (posicio_taulell == NULL) {
        printf("\nError al reservar memoria.\n");
    }
    else {
     for (i = 0;  i < filas;  i++) {
        posicio_taulell[i] = (char *)malloc (columnas * sizeof(char)); // PERSISTENTE
        if (posicio_taulell[i] == NULL) {
            printf("\nError al reservar memoria.\n");
        }
    }
    i = 0;
}
```

Y tienes razón, pero solo a medias. El orden de las cosas aquí es muy importante. Fíjate que en el cambio local estás modificando la dirección de memoria a la cual apunta el puntero, puntero que como hemos dicho es local, luego a partir de ese momento el puntero ya no apuntará a la misma región de memoria que el puntero original declarado en la función `main`, a partir de ese momento los cambios *persistentes* se realizan en una región de memoria desconocida para la función `main`.

Por ponerlo de forma un poco más gráfica, en main tenemos un puntero doble que no está inicializado, luego la dirección de memoria a la que apunta es aleatoria aunque para nuestro caso y por claridad asumamos que se trata de la dirección `0x1000`. Algo así:

```
main::posicio_taulell         -> 0x1000
```

Pues bien, con este puntero llamamos a `funcionModulo`, con lo que se crea un segundo puntero local a dicha función. Nota que ambos punteros apuntan a la misma zona de memoria (comparten memoria), aunque recordemos que la misma no es válida al no estar el puntero de `main` inicializado.

```
main::posicio_taulell         -> 0x1000
funcionModulo:posicio_taulell -> 0x1000
```

Después se llama al `malloc` local y las cosas se empiezan a torcer. Ahora cada puntero apunta a una región diferente de la memoria.

```
main::posicio_taulell         -> 0x1000 (NO VALIDA)
funcionModulo:posicio_taulell -> 0x2000 (VALIDA)
```

Después de esto se hacen algunas operaciones sobre el puntero de `funcionModulo`, pero como las direcciones de memoria no coinciden nadie se entera... finalmente la ejecución abandona `funcionModulo` y con ello perdemos su puntero, con lo que solo nos queda el puntero de `main`:

```
main::posicio_taulell         -> 0x1000 (NO VALIDA)
```

Y claro, este puntero sigue apuntando a una región de memoria no válida. Hemos creado una fuga de memoria, ya que hemos hecho una reserva de memoria que no sabemos dónde se encuentra y, por tanto, no podemos ni usar ni liberar.

La solución pasa por usar un puntero triple (da escalofríos, lo se, pero es lo que hay):

- Para inicializar un `int` desde una función necesitamos un puntero a `int`
- Para inicializar un puntero a `int`, necesitamos un puntero doble.
- Para inicializar un puntero doble, necesitamos... exacto, un puntero triple. Tenemos que incrementar la indirección.

Algo así:

```
void funcionModulo(char ***posicio_taulell) {
    int filas = 9, columnas = 9;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char aux;
    *posicio_taulell = (char **)malloc (filas * sizeof(char*));
    if (*posicio_taulell == NULL) {
        printf("\nError al reservar memoria.\n");
    }
    else {
     for (i = 0;  i < filas;  i++) {
        (*posicio_taulell)[i] = (char *)malloc (columnas * sizeof(char));
        if ((*posicio_taulell)[i] == NULL) {
            printf("\nError al reservar memoria.\n");
        }
    }
    i = 0;
}

// ....
case 1:
  //printf("\nAntes de comenzar es %c", posicio_taulell[0][0]);
  funcionModulo(&posicio_taulell);
```

Y listo, ahora ya serás capaz de inicializar el puntero doble dentro de una función.